# Error Response from Paypal re: email

Tags: php, email, paypal

A newbie here, I don't have a clue why paypal is giving me this error. 
Here is the code:

```
<?php
require ("private/PayPal/vendor/autoload.php");
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

$sid = session_id();
$idArtObject = ($_GET['idArtObject']);
$fourdigitid = leadingZero($idArtObject);
$art = find_object_by_id($idArtObject);
$total = $art['price'];

$apiContext = new PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(Client id, Secret id)
);

$payer = new PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal($total);
$amount->setCurrency('USD');

$transaction = new PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);

$redirectUrls = new PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls>setReturnUrl("https://dev.sandywilsonart.com/ppreturn.php");

$redirectUrls>setCancelUrl("https://dev.sandywilsonart.com/ppcancel.php");
$payment = new PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
    echo $payment;
    echo "\n\nRedirect user to approval url: " . $payment>getApprovalLink() . "\n";
}
catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getData();
}
?>

<body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<div class="flex-container">
<div class='flex-item'>
<img src="public/images/thumbNails/
<?php echo $art['idArtObject'];>.jpg">
</br>
ID:
<?php
    if ($art['category'] != 'wc') {
        echo '</br>Title: ';
        echo $art['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Watercolor';
    }
?>
<br/>
<?php
    echo $art['height'];
    echo " inches by ";
    echo $art['width'];
    echo " inches<br/>";
    echo "Purchase Price: ";
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_US");
    if ($art['price']>0) {
        $total = $total + $art['price'];
        echo money_format('%.2n', $art['price']);
    } else {
        echo "NFS";
    }
?>
    </div>
</div>  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="nonote" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" 
value="public/images/ppbuynowbtn.jpg" />
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="Audrea" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="Elliott" />
    <input type="hidden" name="payeremail" 
value="wordartlady@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="idArtObject" value="<?php echo 
$idArtObject; ?>" />
    <center>
    <h4>Total: <?php echo money_format('%.2n', $total) ?></h4>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Payment"/>
</center>
</form>
```

---

The error I receive back is this:

> "We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with
>   the  PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the
>   seller  to resolve the problem. If this payment is for an eBay
>   listing, you can  contact the seller via the "Ask Seller a Question"
>   link on the listing  page. When you have the correct email address,
>   payment can be made at  www.paypal.com."

Someone out there help...please?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're adding much info about the payer, including email address, which makes sense with the error you're getting. Just from looking at the API docs, it looks like you're supposed to supply some of those details by creating a PayerInfo object that you pass to the Payer's setPayerInfo method. https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.Payer.html#_setPayerInfo

Comment: I'm not seeing how the PHP code at the top relates to the HTML/PHP code at the bottom.  Is this all one page?  Additionally, there are a number of PHP and HTML syntax errors here.

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response. I will post a comment when the code finally runs! Yay!

Comment: So I added the PayerInfo Class as follows:      $payerinfo = new PayPal\Api\PayerInfo();
        $payerinfo->setEmail("wordartlady@gmail.com");

    $payer = new PayPal\Api\Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
        $payer->setPayerInfo($payerinfo);  But receive same error.